# Biography of Rabbi Mordechai Carlebach

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, biography

A very popular book in the "yeshivishe" world is the Sefer Chavatzeles Hasharon by Rabbi Mordechai Carlebach.

It has many shiurim on the Parsha, with a lot of lomdus.

I am wondering if anyone knows anything about the author, as this sefer is very fascinating.
I could not find anything about him online.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Is this on topic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He lives in Yerushalayim, on Rechov Techeiles Mordechai in Romema.

He is very young - and was even younger when he began publishing his sefarim.

He is an alumnus of Brisk and R' Moshe Shapira, and currently learns in one of R Yackov Hillel's kollelim.

His father is R' Moshe Carlebach (author of Poseach Shearim), and his father-in-law is R' Akiva Kister zt"l.

Besides for his sefarim on the Parsha, he contributes frequently to the weekly *gilyon* מסביב לשולחן. Past issues are available [here](http://beinenu.com/alonim?title=%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%91%D7%99%D7%91%20%D7%9C%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F&field_year_value_many_to_one=All&tid=).

Comment: I think his address and where he davens is a little too much information to publicize on a public site like this.

Comment: His address is written in the front of every sefer he has published.

Comment: I edited out where he davens, although it is no secret

Comment: https://www.kolhalashon.com/New/Ravs.aspx?&Lang=Hebrew&FID=18816&ROrder=-1